# React Stripe api not working on live but fine on local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I thought i was on the home stretch then bam! back down to earth! and my own deadline is creeping right up on me!

Final got everything working on local with a stripe payment form, and pushed live and somehow i get a message from my api code saying

console error:

```
POST https://example.com/api/charge 400 (Bad Request)
```

{ "message":"Missing required param: amount." },

pretty new to all this but any help will be awesome! code posted below in

my charges.js file

```
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.SECRET_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { id, amount } = req.body;

  try {
    const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency: "AUD",
      description: "Delicious empanadas",
      payment_method: id,
      confirm: true,
    });

    console.log(payment);

    return res.status(200).json({
      confirm: "abc123",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

my checkoutform.js

```
const CheckoutForm = ({ success }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [isProcessing, setProcessingTo] = useState(false);
  const [checkoutError, setCheckoutError] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
      billing_details: {
        name: event.target.name.value,
        address: {
          city: event.target.city.value,
          line1: event.target.line1.value,
          line2: event.target.line2.value,
        },
      },
    });

    setProcessingTo(true);

    if (!error) {
      const { id } = paymentMethod;

      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post("/api/charge", { id, amount: 2000 });
        console.log(data);
        success();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: It appears that around line 9 of your code sample here that the amount isn't being passed  as a `key: value`. That should fix at least that error. https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message says that you are not passing parameter `amount` which is obligatory.

Documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create

```
const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 100,
  currency: "AUD",
  description: "Delicious empanadas",
  payment_method: id,
  confirm: true,
});
```